# Does git checkout file can raise a conflict

Tags: git

If i were to checkout a file from branch a to branch b.
Does a conflict can be raised when merging both into branch c?
Conflict regarding the same code in both branches (a & b -> c)..

Comment: yes, there can be conflicts if you are trying to merge a file from two branches into a third branch, and the file in the two branches has conflicting changes in it.

Comment: @topsail thanks for the reply, seems like so..

Answer (score 1):

Via your question title, you have (probably inadvertently) raised a fairly complicated question, because `git checkout` (and its newer `git switch` counterpart) has a *merge mode*.  I am certain this is not what you were asking about, but it's worth mentioning: if you use `git checkout -m` you invoke Git's three-way merge on individual files.  How this works is extra-complicated, and I won't cover it here, as this is a more basic answer—but it means that `git checkout -m otherbranch` can have merge conflicts *during the checkout*.  You were, though, asking about using `git merge`.  **(None of this is about `git checkout`, with or without `-m`.)**

The trick here is to realize what **merge**, treated as a verb<sup>1</sup> ("to merge", i.e., to merge some commit with another commit) *means*.  So: what *does* merge mean?  It doesn't mean *make my file match theirs*, because if it did, what would happen to any changes you made on purpose?  It doesn't mean *make their file match mine* either, of course, for the same reason turned around the other way (you'd lose *their* changes).  **Thus, merging must have to do with *combining changes*, or in other words, *combining work done*.  A *conflict* occurs when Git is unable to do this combining on its own.**

Let's pause for a moment here and observe something fundamental about Git: **A Git commit stores a *full snapshot of every file that Git knew about* (at the time you, or whoever, made the commit).**<sup>2</sup>  Commits don't *store* changes, only snapshots.  Yet, when we look at some commit, we usually *view* it as changes.  The way Git shows us changes (instead of snapshots) is by taking *two* snapshots—two [frames of film from a movie reel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Film_frame), as it were—and *comparing* them.  Some files are completely unchanged, from one commit to the next,<sup>3</sup> and some are not; for those that are not, Git [computes a diff](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_comparison) and shows you that.

Once we consider the fact that each commit stores a *snapshot*, and add to that the fact that commits link (backwards) to previous commits—it's this commit-to-previous-commit linkage that forms history in a Git repository—we have all the ingredients to work out *how* Git does a `git merge`.  It's still not obvious yet, but we're almost there.

To make it obvious, let's *draw* some commits.  Now, each commit in a real repository has some big, ugly, random-looking (but unique) hash ID like `9c897eef06347cc5a3eb07c3ae409970ab1052c8`.  This hash ID is in effect the [true name of the commit](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/IKnowYourTrueName), but for our purposes, let's pretend they have one-letter "names" so that we can talk about them much more easily.

Each commit *remembers* (i.e., stores, permanently, just like its snapshot) the hash ID of some previous commit(s).  Most commits remember exactly one previous commit.  We say that the child commit *points to* its parent.  So if `H` stands for our *most recent* commit, we might have:

```
... <-F <-G <-H
```

in the repository: commit `H` *points to* its parent commit `G`, which points to its parent `F`, which in turn points to another parent, and so on.

As we make *new* commits, we simply add on to the repository, extending out the chain.  To keep track of our new commits, we use *branch names*, which Git automatically adjusts so that they point to the latest commit in the series.  So once we've added two commits to the above, we might have a picture like this:

```
          I--J   <-- ourbranch (HEAD)
         /
...--G--H   <-- main
```

The *name* `main` remembers that there's a series of commits that end (right now anyway) at commit `H`.  But there are two more commits past that point: our two *new* commits `I-J` on `ourbranch`.<sup>4</sup>  The parent of `J` is `I`, and the parent of `I` is `H`.

Now suppose someone else has made *another* branch, *also starting at commit `H`*, and has added two commits to *their* branch:

```
          I--J   <-- ourbranch (HEAD)
         /
...--G--H   <-- main
         \
          K--L   <-- theirbranch
```

A merge operation, in Git, will *combine work*.  The *work done* in our series of commits `I-J` is what we see if we compare `H` vs `I` and then `I` vs `J`, and the *work done* in their commits is what we see if we compare `H` vs `K` and then `K` vs `L`.

It turns out that, aside from some corner cases,<sup>5</sup> Git can use a short-cut here: instead of comparing `H` vs `I`, then `I` vs `J`, Git can just compare `H`—the snapshot in it, that is—directly to `J`, to see what work we did.  Meanwhile Git can compare `H` directly to `L`, to see what work they did.

**So `git merge` means *run two diffs to find two sets of work*.**  Having found those two sets of work, Git *combines* them.  If the combining goes well, there are no merge conflicts.  If the combining goes poorly, there are merge conflicts.  But consider those two diffs again.  They both start from commit `H`.  They *must* start from the same commit, so that Git can combine work (Git applies the *combined* work *to* the starting-point snapshot).  **How does Git know to use commit `H`?**

The answer is staring us in the face, in the picture we drew.  The branches *come together* at commit `H`, if you work backwards the way Git does.  They *split apart* at commit `H`, if you work forwards the way people do.  Commit `H` is shared, and it's the *best* shared commit (earlier commits like `G` and `F` are shared too but they're "further back in time" as it were).

The technical algorithm Git uses to find a merge base is the [Lowest Common Ancestor algorithm with adjustments to work on a Directed Acyclic Graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lowest_common_ancestor#Extension_to_directed_acyclic_graphs), but the short, non-technical version is "the obvious best ancestor commit", which is easy to see in *simple* graphs.  Try running `git log --all --decorate --oneline --graph` to see if *your* graph is simple, and whether you can spot the merge bases!

So:

> If I were to [copy] a file from [the tip commit of] branch **A** to [a new commit in] branch **B**, [can] a conflict [occur] when merging both into branch **C**?

It can.  It won't necessarily do so.  The critical questions will revolve around the *merge base* commit—the common starting-point commit that Git will find, from its commit graph—and what that diff shows to the two commits you're merging.  That is, there's some common starting point, and that provides a *third* (or first: merge base) version of that file.  We aren't told, here, what's in that *third* version.  Then we have some version of that file in the tip-most commit of branch **A**, some version of that file in the tip-most commit of branch **B**, and some version of that file in the tip-most commit of branch **C**.  You've proposed to make a new tip-most commit in **B** such that the copies in **A** and **B** match up.  But we don't know what's in the *merge base* version, nor what's in the branch **C** version.

To predict, or find out, whether there will be any merge conflict, we'll need to find the merge base commit—the best *shared* commit—and see what's in that file there, and also see what's in the latest branch-**C** commit version of that same file.  That is, we need to find a merge base and run two `git diff`s.  (Since you've proposed doing *two* merges, we need to find *two* merge bases.)

**If you only remember one or two things here, remember that `git merge` has *three* inputs, not two, and that it runs *two* `git diff` commands.**  Well, that, and that commits hold *snapshots and metadata* (snapshots, plus stuff like the log message and commit author), and that *branch names* help Git find commits for you: Git needs the big ugly hash IDs, but humans are bad at those, so Git lets us use branch names, and the branch names find the hash IDs.

---

<sup>1</sup>Note that in Git, we also have *a merge*, or *a merge commit:* merge as a noun or adjective.  A *merge commit* is one with two or more parents, and *a merge* is the noun variant of this.

<sup>2</sup>Curiously, there are systems that work entirely differently, yet they wind up doing mostly the same thing and mostly having the same issues.  In some sense this particular fundamental thing about Git doesn't matter.  It's still important to know, though: it winds up explaining many other things about Git.

<sup>3</sup>In the snapshots saved with commits, Git keeps each files' content in a *de-duplicated* form, so that identical contents are shared across separate commits, and even within a single commit.  (The files' names are stored separately from their content.)  This de-duplication not only saves tremendous amounts of space, since most commits mostly duplicate most of the files from the previous commit, it also makes identifying unchanged files very easy, speeding up the process of turning a commit into a diff.

<sup>4</sup>Git chooses to claim that the commits up through and including `H` are on *both branches*.  This, too, is important to know when using Git, although there are other systems that prove that you can operate in other ways.

<sup>5</sup>These corner cases—like renaming files, for instance—are an argument that Git *shouldn't* do the short-cut here.

Comment: Well, except for the first paragraph, the entire answer is about `git merge`. The first paragraph says that I'm not going to talk about `git checkout`... (edited to make that clearer, I think)

Comment: plus I re-read the question, and my comment completely misses what he OP is asking

Comment: First of all, thank you for that huge explanation!
Regarding my question, is about pulling some change of a file from branch a into branch b (mine) while in future, both will be merged into branch c..
So I wanted to know if that approach can raise conflicts.. which I can guess that it will..